# How to enable required text field on submit only in an Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, checkbox, textfield

I have the following template with textbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="s_i{{i}}" name="s_i{{i}}" (change)="clickObj($event, myObjs[i])" [(ngModel)]="myObjs[i].isSelected">
<input type="text" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" [required]="myObjs[i].isSelected"
 id="f_p_{{i}}" name="p_p_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="myObjs[i]">
```

When clicking on the checkbox the textfield become red automatically and not
let the user a chance to enter value.
I need to mark error only when clicking submit. Any idea what should I change/add in order fix this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you in a ngFor loop ? If so, the loops and template driven forms aren't very compatible, that would explain your issue.

Comment: I'm on a loop yes, and I get only the applicable text box which its checkbox is clicked so it's look like the loop is fine. When clicking on checkbox I make the textfield to become enable as well. [disabled]="false"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Boolean variable that will determine whether the field will be required.

in TS:

```
submitClicked:boolean = false;
....
toggleSubmitClicked(){
    this.submitClicked = ! this.submitClicked
}
```

Then, in HTML:

```
[required]="submitClicked && myObjs[i].isSelected" 
   (submit)="toggleSubmitClicked()"  (click)="toggleSubmitClicked()"
```

Comment: I've update the code with this fix, it works after 1 submit only because the value is true and remain true. When should the value go back to false? In what event?

Comment: @user2304483, (I made the answer anew)                  you can add  (click)="toggleSubmitClicked()" So if the user starts typing again, it will work out

Comment: It's a bit more complicated because as you can see I'm on a loop.